# I'm looking for a command to find all commits which fix my commits

Tags: git, grep, blame

I'm working on a project with the following git naming convention :

- For a feature, we name our commit by starting with feat like that : `feat(myFeature): my feature description`
- For a fix, its the same but we use the keyword fix like this: 
  `fix(myFix): my fix description`

To improve myself, i want to know when my commit are fixed. 
I'm not a git guru, i know there are possibilities with git command with grep and blame but i don't know how to mix them.

I'm looking for a git shell command with my name in input which gives me on **output all fix commit on my commits**.

Answer (score 0):

Set your alias with

```
git config --global alias.myfixes 'git log --oneline --grep=fix --author=<yourName>'
```

then to use it, just do

```
git myfixes
```

Optionally, you could add the `--all` flag to the log command in the alias, if you want the search to occur on all branches, not only the current one.

Also, I opted here for a standard `--oneline`, but of course you might want to replace it with something closer to your specific needs.

---

As suggested by Ry in comments, depending on your role in the workflow, choose between `--author=<yourName>` and `--committer=<yourName>` accordingly.

Comment: This looks like a command to find all fixes an author made, not all fixes made to features an author committed.

Comment: @Ry Hmm, you might be right, I had wondered but it's unsure from the way the question is asked. But for completion, yes, I'll edit.